# SEO : Adding to Google other than submitting directly for google's crawler - http://www.enshaeyah.webs.com

Tags: seo, web-crawler

What are other ways of making your website searchable by Google, other than submitting the link directly to Google.

Submitting links to yahoo is a breeze, gets crawled for a day or two... Google though takes a while...

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add a link to your website on a website that's already indexed by google, google will follow that and reach your site without you needing to submit to their page. it's actually not recommended to submit your site to their page because then you're put at the end of the queue. but if you have a link on a page that google indexes in the next minute, it will get to you much faster. more links on many pages with higher ranking the better. cheers

Comment: Great. This site is already indexed by google, if i type http://www.enshaeyah.webs.com , will google's crawler reach this link?

Comment: I tried searching for "enshaeyah" and the actual returned result opens this forum thread. It doesn't show a link that goes directly to enshaeyah's home page. :(

Answer (score 1):

Add your site to DMOZ.org, and encourage everyone you know to link to your site. The more places that link to your site, the more likely it'll get indexed sooner (and more fully), and the better it will rank.

Also, if your site is very large, it is not unreasonable to sign up for their webmaster tools and submit a sitemap index. This is especially effective for fast ranking, and showing up in obscure search results, but it will not help you rank for difficult terms.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that if your site was visited by googlebot,
it doesn't necessarily end up in the google index.

Use this link to check:
http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/sitestatus